# How to use TL-WN722N as an Access Point

Tags: access-point, pop-os

I'm trying to figure out how to turn my TL-WN722N USB WiFi adapter into a simple access point. My OS is Pop!_OS 20.10, so basically Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, both my build in pcie wireless card and the usb one supports AP and i can turn it on from GUI cuz pop os supports that, thanks again.